# Create a Django patch which update several instances

Tags: python, django

I'm asking a question about my Django application updates.
I'm working on my Django Development server and I would like to know How I could create a patch which will update my different Django Project installed on different servers.

**For example :**

In my Dev' server, I add a new Query in my script. Then I would like to add this new Query to my all virtual instances by updating my script and not just copy/past modifications. It could work for one query, but if I have 200 rows, copy/paste will be too long.
I launch a patch which will make all updates without manually copy/paste rows.

How it's possible to do that ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably consider migrating your project to a [version control system.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control)

Then every time you are changing something to your local copy of the code and `push` the changes on the repository, you can `fetch`/`rebase`/`pull` your changes wherever you want (be it your server or another computer of yours), and your patches will be applied without copy/pasting!

Some version control systems to consider:

- [Git Lab](https://about.gitlab.com/) allowing the creation of free private repositories
- [Github](https://github.com/) the "old reliable", but no free private repositories
- [Bit Bucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) (don't use it myself but it is widely used!)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer ! Do you thing that Git Lab/Github is a very 'professional' way to make an update of all instances in a same time ? Soon I could have 12.000 servers with my Django project on each one.

Comment: You will still need to log in to every server and `fetch`/`rebase`/`pull` your changes to patch each code-base in each server separately, but yes, this is a professional way! 
BTW, 12.000 servers? o_O wow!

Comment: Ok perfect ! Yes about 12.000 servers because it's a national project for 4 countries ;)

Comment: Good luck with that :)